# Finding rows that have many similar values and one different one

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to isolate a problem with a violation of a unique key index. I'm pretty certain that the cause is resulting from columns that have the same value in 3 columns not having the same value in the 4th (when they should). As an example...

```
Key   Column1   Column2   Column3   Column4
1       A          B         C         D
2       A          B         C         D
3       A          B         C         D
4       A          B         C         Z
```

I basically want to select column 4, or some way to let me identify column 4. I know it's a matter of using aggregrate functions but I'm not very familiar with them. Can anyone assist on a way to select Key, Column4 for rows that have a different column 4 value and the same column 1-3 values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want:

```
select column1, column2, column3
from t
group by column1, column2, column3
having min(column4) <> max(column4)
```

Once you get the right values for the first three columns, you can join back in to get the specific rows.

Or, you can use window functions like this:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, min(column4) over (partition by column1, column2 column3) as min4,
             max(column4) over (partition by column1, column2 column3) as max4
      from t
     ) t
where min4 <> max4;
```

If `NULL` is a valid "other" value that you want to count, you will need additional logic for that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get all columns, then (it could be simpler if windowed `count` supported `distinct` but it's not):

```
with cte1 as (
    select distinct * from Table1
), cte2 as (
    select
        *,
        count(column4) over(partition by column1, column2, column3) as cnt
    from cte1
)
select * from cte2 where cnt > 1;
```

if you want just to select key:

```
select
    column1, column2, column3
from Table1
group by column1, column2, column3
having count(distinct column4) > 1
```

[**<kbd>sql fiddle demo</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5bc68/3)